# sw2urdf window closes instantly

Tags: ros, sw-urdf-exporter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've installed the SW2URDF add on in solidworks 2019, but when I open a part and go tools->export as URDF the window flashes open and then shuts instantly. I can't export anything as a urdf. Does anyone know why this might be? My .NET framework is 4.8.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372249/sw2urdf-window-closes-instantly/) by [rapidnailcalculator](https://answers.ros.org/users/70407/rapidnailcalculator/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2021-02-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On SW 2020 with SW2URDF version 1.6 try exporting assembly, a single part exerts the same behaviour as in the question

---

Originally posted by [avzmpy](https://answers.ros.org/users/56476/avzmpy/) with karma: 83 on 2021-03-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ShayS.](https://answers.ros.org/users/55481/shays./) on 2021-05-21**:
Thanks, this answer has fixed my problem. It seems the SW2URDF exporter only works on assemblies, not individual part files as the tutorials for the plug-in [here](https://wiki.ros.org/sw_urdf_exporter/Tutorials/Export%20a%20Part) suggests.If anyone else is experiencing this problem, I would recommend just skipping the part tutorial and going to the next tutorial, the one on exporting assemblies to URDF.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Which version are you using? For SW 2019, I believe 1.5.1 works better than 1.6

---

Originally posted by [brawner](https://answers.ros.org/users/2146/brawner/) with karma: 581 on 2021-02-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rapidnailcalculator](https://answers.ros.org/users/70407/rapidnailcalculator/) on 2021-02-20**:
Ah, I was using version 1.6 of SW2URDF. I've downloaded 1.5.1 now and it seems to have solved it. Brilliant. Thank you for your help!